# Turn string into multi dimensional array with keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, explode

I am coding a PHP function, and I would like to ask a question. I have a problem with exploding a string in a particular way. I have tried to explain as well as I can down below.

**What is this?**

Well.. I am working on a solution to decrease the number of tables on my website. I can turn the table for admin rights into one field in the user table. However, I will then need to explode the text field into an array when loading the website. The code is looking like:

```
<?php
$string = "server1=(ban=(perm=false,normal=true),edit=true,delete=false),adminlog=true,server2=(ban=(perm=false,normal=true),edit=false,delete=true)";

function parseRights( $s="" ){
 $context = array();

 // code here
}

print_r(parseRights($string));
?>
```

Basically, I would want the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [server1] => Array
        (
            [ban] => Array
                (
                    [perm] => false
                    [normal] => true
                )

            [edit] => true
            [delete] => false
        )

    [adminlog] => true
    [server2] => Array
        (
            [ban] => Array
                (
                    [perm] => false
                    [normal] => false
                )

            [edit] => false
            [delete] => true
        )

)
```

True and false should be PHP true and false. If written out like that, I know it will show 1 where true are, and nothing where 0 are.. but it's just to show you what I would like the array to look like after run through the function. I would like it to be able to create an "infinite" array, with each new parentheses creating a new array. Of cource I would gladly accept other ways to distinguish the correct rights if the function would work in the same manner.

Comment: Why are you starting with a string like that in the first place?  You could just start with the array, or JSON.

Comment: It is going to connect to the database and get the string from the user table... this is only due to testing purposes.. I have not yet connected to the database. All I want to check if it is doable to explode it into a multi dimensional array. I would like to do that inside a function to use that function where I want on the website.

Comment: Doable but why it's way to complex.  Either store this in a relational structure in the DB or at wors't store a serialized array in the DB, then one line transforms it back into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you along a little.  Better would be to have related tables that store each functional piece, such as a *ban* table and *permission* table both related to the *servers* table or something similar.  If you're not going to store this properly in the database, at least save some trouble:

```
$array = array('server1'=>array('ban'=>array('perm'=>false,'normal'=>true),'edit'=>true,'delete'=>false));

$string = json_encode($array);
echo $string;
/*
{"server1":{"ban":{"perm":false,"normal":true},"edit":true,"delete":false}}
*/
$new_array = json_decode($string, true);
var_export($new_array);
/*
array
 (
  'server1' =>
  array (
    'ban' =>
    array (
      'perm' => false,
      'normal' => true,
    ),
    'edit' => true,
    'delete' => false,
  ),
)
*/
```

See how the JSON string looks **eerily similar** to your string?  You could also use `serialize()` but JSON is standardized and portable.

Also, `var_dump()` and `var_export()` will show that `true` and `false` are actually stored, `print_r()` just doesn't display the proper type.